# Unable to set state after executing componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I have the following `state` variable and `componentDidMount` method on my component:

```
  state = {
    categorized_items: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchItems()
    // I'm trying to do the following
    console.log('uncat_items: ', this.props.uncat_items)
    this.setState({categorized_items: this.props.uncat_items})
  }
  render () {....}

  function mapStateToProps({ items_reducer }) {
    return {
     uncat_items: items_reducer.uncat_items
    }
  }
```

The `this.props.fetchItems()` action method fetches a number of items and updates the `uncat_items` in the redux store just fine (I can see the expected values for the `this.props.uncat_items` variable in the render/other methods without any problem). However, what I need to do for this particular case is right after the `fetchItems` method is executed and it updates the `uncat_items` in the store, I need to call `setState` and update the `categorized_items` in the state with `uncat_items`. I know calling `this.setState` like this in the `componentDidMount` method is not correct, but I don't know how to do that. As you can see I tried printing out `this.props.uncat_items`, but that returns an empty array, even though it executed the action method and updated in the reducer properly. Can someone please give me an idea how to do it the right way? Basically, after `componentDidMount` executes, set the state with a particular variable from the updated redux store.

Comment: Your `console.log()` yielded an empty array because it's not an asynchronous call; it executed before `fetchItems()` returned any data. (If `fetchItems()` returns a promise, you can fix this pretty easily.)

Comment: why not just use `this.props.uncat_items` directly in the render function (or wherever you want to use `this.state.categorized_items`) ?

Comment: Unless you need to edit a separate copy of the data, best practice would be not to copy your props into your state. Instead you can use conditional rendering in the `render` function like `return this.props.uncat_items.length > 0 ? <ul>...</ul> : <p>No items</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you invoke an asynchronous action (`this.props.fetchItems()`) and then immediately invoke `this.setState()` - which happens before the `fetchItems` request finishes (thus, before `props.uncat_items` gets populated).

Assuming you are using newest React, depending on your particular use case, you can either:

1) Drop state and just use directly `this.props.uncat_items` in the render function.

2) Use `static getDerivedStateFromProps` to update state due to new props.

**However**, as mentioned in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), it's not really recommended, as most cases can be handled differently (e.g. by switching to a controlled component, as stated in solution #1). A longer description can be found in [this article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), which is also mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method. It looks like when your component is mounting your store might still contain the default value for that piece of state. It then updates correctly in the redux store as you mentioned but the component state is not updated.

To update component state after new props are received by the component:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  // compare prevProps to current props and update
  if(this.props.uncat_items !== prevProps.uncat_items) {
    this.setState({categorized_items: this.props.uncat_items})
    }
  }
```

As mentioned in comments, using props directly in the render method is the more ideal solution as you don’t want your component to needlessly re-render.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an optimal solution, as this will trigger another rerender of the component

Comment: Yes ideally the prop should be used directly as per the react docs. Though It’s useful to demonstrate to op why the prop and state is not what he expects at that instance of the component’s life cycle.